# If all edges in a network have distinct capacities, then the min-cut is unique

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, directed-graphs

I'm stuck trying to prove that *If all edges in a network have distinct capacities, then the min-cut is unique*. I'd like to know if there is some proof that doesn't involve going through F&F algorithm, or designing one. Instead, I tried proving it by contradiction, assuming the existence of two different cuts with equal capacities (and both minimums) but I don't know how to arrive to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the following counterexample for the claim you trying to prove.

[image]